# vue-formulate group custom remove not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate, vue-slot

I have a piece of code that use Vue-Formulate with group feature and I try to implement custom button to remove nested items;

```html
<FormulateInput 
  type="group"
  :name="field.name"
  v-bind="field.attributes"
  remove-position="after"
>
  <div ....>
    <div .... v-for loop>
      <FormulateInput 
        :type="_field.type"
        :name="_field.name"
        ....
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div slot="remove"> <!-- adding slot to customize remove -->
    <FormulateInput
      type="button"
    >
      Remove Student
    </FormulateInput>
  </div>
</FormulateInput>
```

Such addiction change default `<a ...>` link to button but functionality of removing item being lost.
Documentation of this slot says:

> "The remove button when repeatable. The context object in this slot
> includes the index and a removeItem function that should be called to
> remove that item."

I am not sure how to add `removeItem` function call to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `removeItem` slot prop is only provided to [repeatable groups](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/group/#repeatable-groups), so make sure to set `repeatable` on the `FormulateInput` with `type=group`.
2. To insert a custom remove-button in the `remove` [scoped slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots), wrap the button in a `<template v-slot:remove="{ removeItem }">`, and set `removeItem` as the button's `click`-handler via the [`v-on`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on) directive (`@click` for shorthand):

```html
<FormulateInput type="group" repeatable 1️⃣>
  <FormulateInput name="name" label="Student’s name" />
  <FormulateInput type="email" name="email" label="Student’s email" />

  2️⃣
  <template v-slot:remove="{ removeItem }">
    <FormulateInput type="button" @click="removeItem"> Remove Student </FormulateInput>
  </template>
</FormulateInput>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-formulate-with-custom-remove-button?file=src%2FApp.vue)